# Search VI for letters and numbers

Tags: regex, linux, search, vim, vi

I use vi at work and i have to search for a string of specific letters & numbers such as these:

```
UTL41650

adr21100

aTL31901
```

there are always (3)Letters and (5)Numbers. Is there a way to search for these strings easily? Maybe with regex or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just type

```
/\v[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{5}
```

The `\v` activates the [very magic mode](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic) to avoid escaping here. What follows is probably self-explanatory, assuming you know that `\d` is a digit in regular expressions.

[Documentation on searching in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Searching)

Comment: Thanks Denys for the answer and the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
(\w{3})(\d{5})
```

Also check out

[VimRegex](http://vimregex.com/#substitute)

Comment: Be careful that \w includes digits

Comment: That is true. Should specify [a-z][A-Z] which I see you did earlier

Comment: FYI: `\a` is the same as `[a-zA-Z]`